# C# passing an optional parameter of type object

Tags: c#, class, optional-parameters

I got this code here that takes a string parameter:

```
public static void DisplayText(string Default)
{
    foreach (char c in Default)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
        Thread.Sleep(25);
    }
}
```

Now, what I need is to be able to make this code works so it can also take multiple parameters:

```
DisplayText("Welcome to you, {0} the {1}.", player.Name, player.Class);
```

But I also need to be able to only put a string parameter with nullable object parameters. I tried this code here:

I tried using the nullable<> but It got me nowhere.

Now, any pointers?

Comment: How about a look at documentaion? Optional arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: Sounds like you can use _Optional_ parameters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx *Edit: @CrudaLilium You beat me there :)

Comment: I always get lost reading the documentation, but thanks for the link :)

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but even just googling would be fine, this quite basic stuff.
@uteist Indeed I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While looking for one of my answers, I came up with my comment here.
I know this has already been answered but, you can also use *String Interpolation* (C# 6.0) and keep your method as it is.

```
public static void DisplayText(string Default)
{
    //I have simplified the method but you get the point
    Console.WriteLine(Default);
}

class Player
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    Player player = new Player();
    player.Name = "uTeisT";
    player.Class = "Novice";

    //Passing the parameter with new feature
    //Results in more readable code and ofc no change in current method
    DisplayText($"Welcome to you, {player.Name} the {player.Class}.");
}
```

And the output will be:

> Welcome to you, uTeisT the Novice.

Comment: Hey thanks, I like that better actually, I'm all for cleaner code! :)

Comment: @SirMaxwell Well, at least give me an upvote then :p

Answer (score 3):

Why not use `String.Format()` with your input.

So call:

`DisplayText(String.Format("Welcome to you, {0} the {1}.", player.Name, player.Class));`

`String.Format()` takes a string plus an array (`params`) of other strings, that are assigned to the {0} and {1} locations.

I.E

```
string str = String.Format("Welcome to you, {0} the {1}.", player.Name, player.Class);
DisplayText(str);
//str = "Welcome to you, bob the greatest"
```

Failing that, you will need to create an overloaded `DisplayText()` method with your requirements.

Something like:

```
 private static void DisplayText(string message, params string[] otherStrings)
 {       
   // otherStrings will be null or contain an array of passed-in-strings 
        string str = string.Format(message, otherString);
        foreach (char c in str)
        {
            Console.Write(c);
            Thread.Sleep(25);
        }       
 }
```

Doing the overload method will give you 2 options in your intellisense when you type `DisplayText();` one for each of the signatures.

Comment: So I'm using the string format method, but the second method looks more appealing, I tried using it, but fail to understand how it works exactly.

Comment: against better judgement (normally better to ask a new Q) i've added an example for you.